# Linked List Recursion in Java with Node as Parameter

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, nodes

for a class project I built a custom linked list that maintains Node objects of class Student.
In one method, int countNodesRec(Node list), I must pass a Node object as a parameter. While adding my Student objects to the linked list, they are stored as Node objects in the linked list. However, I have no idea how to pass the head node object as the parameter so I may recursively traverse through the linked list. Also, I don't need help with the code for that method. My classes are designed exactly as specified by the project, by the way. Thank you for the help!

TestList Class:

```
public class TestList {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1 = new Student("Adams", 3.9, 26);
    Student s2 = new Student("Lewis", 2.1, 29);
    Student s3 = new Student("Lopez", 4.0, 53);
    Student s4 = new Student("Smith", 3.2, 22);
    Student s5 = new Student("Zeeler", 3.6, 38);
    LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList list3 = new LinkedList();
    //Adds students to LinkedLists and invokes methods to display their data
    list1.addFront(s1);
    list1.addFront(s2);
    list1.addFront(s3);
    list1.addFront(s4);
    list1.addFront(s5);
    list1.printLinkedList();
    System.out.println("Best student: " + list1.bestStudent());       
    list1.countNodesRec(//Don't know how to pass Node);        
  }        
}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student 
{
  private String lastName;
  private double gpa;
  private int age;

  public Student(String lastName, double gpa, int age)
  {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.age = age;    
  }

  public int compareTo(Student s)
  {
    if (gpa < s.gpa)
      return -1;
    else if (gpa > s.gpa)
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return lastName + "\t" + gpa + "\t" + age;
  }

  public double getGpa()
  {
    return gpa;
  }
}
```

LinkedList Class:

```
public class LinkedList 
{
  private Node list;
  public LinkedList()
  {
    list = null;
  }

  // Adds a Node object to the front of the LinkedList
  public void addFront(Student s)
  {
    if (list == null)
      list = new Node(s);
    else
    {
      Node temp = new Node(s);
      // Assigns Node s next reference to the 
      // object at the beginning of the LinkedList
      temp.next = list;
      //Beginning of the list now equals Student s
      list = temp;
    }   
  }

  // Adds a Node object to the back of the LinkedList
  public void addTail(Student s)
  {
    Node node = new Node(s);
    Node current;
    if (list == null)
      list = node;
    else
    {
      current = list;
      while (current.next != null)
        current = current.next;
      current.next = node;
    }
  }

  public Student bestStudent()
  {
    Student bestStudent, bestStudentInner;
    Node current;
    if (list == null)
      return bestStudent = null;
    else
    {
      current = list;
      bestStudentInner = new Student("base case", 0.00, 0);
      while (current != null)
      {
        if (bestStudentInner.getGpa() <= current.data.getGpa())
          bestStudentInner = current.data;
        current = current.next;
      }
      bestStudent = bestStudentInner;
    }
    return bestStudent;
  }

  public void printLinkedList()
  {
    Node current;
    if (list == null)
      System.out.println("Empty");
    else
    {
      current = list;
      while (current != null)
      {
        System.out.println(current.data.toString());
        current = current.next;
      }
    }        
  }

  public int countNodesRec(Node list)
  {
    //To-do here;
  }

   public Student worstStudentRec(Node list)
   {
     //To-do here;
   }



  // Inner class that creates Nodes to be stored in LinkedList  
  private class Node
  {
    public Student data;
    public Node next;

    public Node(Student s)
    {
      data = s;
      next = null;      
    }      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the head node you just need to pass which ever node is the first node in your linkedlist, in this case it's s5. But you take in a student object and create a node around it then add it to your list, currently the only node is list which is a private node object that resides in your list data structure. in order to use the method you would have to pass it a reference to your head, but because it's private there is no way to do that from main. you can make list public and do the following

```
list1.countNodesRec(list1.list);
```

If you don't want to make the Node list object public I suggest you create Node objects with Students inside and pass those to your LinkedList structure. you can also do the following

```
list1.countNodesRec(new Node(s5));
```

The main issue is you're requiring a parameter for countNodesRec but the class LinkedList has a reference to its head so there is no need to pass the head when it's already contained within your LinkedList structure, the Node named list.

Comment: That doesn't work because s5 is a student object. I get an error saying that Student cannot be converted to LinkedList.Node

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using *two* nodes for this routine; since there's no code, I have no idea what functionality requires that duality.

**list1** itself is a reference to the head node of the list.  You use that property repeatedly in your code.  You should be able to call the method with merely **list**.  When you recur, you do so on **this.next**, which is the head of the *rest* of the list.

There's nothing special about a node versus a list head: every node is the head of a list that continues with its **next** reference.

Does that clear up the structure for you?

Comment: I can call the method as list1.countNodesRec(Node list). I just don't know how to pass a Node object which is the head of list1 in that method as a parameter.

Comment: You already *have* the head node!  It's **list1**, which appears as **this** inside the method.  If you insist on two references, you could call it with **list1.countNodesRec(list1)**, but that's redundant and dangerous.  **list1** *is* a Node object.

Comment: ... or do you perhaps want a more direct reference with **list1.list**?  Again, that's dangerous, passing a pair of tightly-related pointers into a routine, but allowing them to appear as unrelated.

Comment: Pardon me, but I tried calling it as list1.countNodesRec(list1), but I'm now getting the error "LinkedList cannot be converted to LinkedList.Node

Comment: Did you try it then with list1.list?  That passes a Node, rather than a LinkedList.  Still, what is it that you're trying to do in the routine that requires **two** list references?

Answer (score 0):

You need a getList() method in your LinkedList class. Then in the test class you should use that method accordingly.
example: list1.countNodesRec(list1.getList())

Answer (score 0):

As the head of the list is a private field, I would add a parameterless method:

```
public int countNodesRec() {
    return countNodesRec(list);
}
```